# How to properly adjust code due to this futurewarning? (multidimensional indexing numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, future-warning

How to adjust the indexing in this code, so that it will work properly due to this FutureWarning?

```
D:/Arc/Arc_Project\Architecture\_Z07_Adjust_X_Y\backward_sequentialize.py:165: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
```

```
a = np.asarray([
           np.asarray([
              np.asarray([1,1,1,1]),
              np.asarray([1,1,0,1]),
              np.asarray([1,1,1,1])
                                  ]),
          np.asarray([
              np.asarray([1,1,1,1]),
              np.asarray([1,1,1,1]),
              np.asarray([1,1,1,1])
                                  ]),
         np.asarray([
              np.asarray([1,1,1,1]),
              np.asarray([1,1,2,1]),
              np.asarray([1,1,1,1])
                                  ])
         np.asarray([
              np.asarray([1,1,1,1]),
              np.asarray([1,1,3,1]),
              np.asarray([1,1,1,1])
                                  ])
         np.asarray([
              np.asarray([1,1,1,1]),
              np.asarray([1,1,4,1]),
              np.asarray([1,1,1,1])
                                  ])
         np.asarray([
              np.asarray([1,1,1,1]),
              np.asarray([1,1,5,1]),
              np.asarray([1,1,1,1])
                                  ]) ])
locs = [2,5]
print(a[[locs]])
         [ [1,1,1,1]
           [1,1,2,1]
           [1,1,1,1] ]
         [ [1,1,1,1]
           [1,1,5,1]
           [1,1,1,1] ]
```

am i getting it right that
locs = tuple([2,5]) will do it?

EDIT: i dont just want the warning to disappear, because as it says it will probably not work properly in the future.

EDIT: I am also doing this: (how to adjust that too?)

```
    a = np.array([x[-(SEQ_LEN):] for x in a])
```

Comment: `a[locs]` should be enough.  You are just selecting blocks 2 and 5 on the first dimension.  Or `a[[2,5], :, :]` (the trailing ':' are automatic).

Comment: `a` is a (6,3,4) shaped array.  You don't need all those `np.asarray`; just one will do.

Comment: What was the purpose for using `[locs]` in the first place?  Or is this old code from someone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accessing the given elements just send the array of the required indices followed by the `,` to represent the other axes and return the required ones in the given axis.

`array[([2,5],)]`, that should take care of it.